# How to change this from manually putting in an Id to auto incrementing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There are quite a few little write ups on this, but I cannot quite get it.

This code works, but I have to manually specify an Id, Id is a foreign key to several other tables:

Seed

```
new Party {Id = "01", startDate = DateTime.Now, endDate = DateTime.Now }
```

Model

```
 public class Party
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    }
```

What I am wanting to do is this though, but when I run `Update-Database -Verbose`, it throws an error saying the Id is being referenced by another table. How do I make `Id` auto generate so that I do not have to reference it when creating a party?:

Seed

```
new Party {startDate = DateTime.Now, endDate = DateTime.Now }
```

Model

```
 public class Party
    {
       [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: are you using code first and data annotations?

Comment: I am using code first via, add-migrations / update-database, so long there is nothing other than that for code first. As far as data annotations are concerned, I have it called in my model and I am not seeing any errors, but there might be something that I am missing.

Comment: I think it was because the Id was a string, I changed it, but now I a mgettign an error when I do Update-Database "could not drop contraint"

Comment: If you have no important data in you DB, I would just Drop all the tables and let it be rebuilt.

Comment: How can I drop the tables? can I simply go to server explorer and click delete on the tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it as `Identity`

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

```
public class Party
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can add the `seed`:

```
protected override void Seed(ConsoleApplication1.TesteContext context)
{
    context.Parties.AddOrUpdate(
        p => p.Id,
        new Party { startDate = DateTime.Now, endDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Party { startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) },
        new Party { startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) },
        new Party { startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4) }
    );
}
```

And you can test it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new TesteContext();

        var parties = ctx.Parties.ToList();

        foreach(var party in parties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {party.Id}, Start: {party.startDate.ToShortDateString()}, End: {party.endDate.ToShortDateString()}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```